# How to turn tuples into columns in a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have the current data:

```
NAME
Andrew        ([1], [0], [100])
Sam           ([1, 2, 3, 4], [0, 0, 0, 0], [100, 100, 100, 100])
Susan         ([1, 2, 3, 4,5], [1, 2, 3, 4, 5], [50, 100, 100, 25, 20])
```

And I would like to turn them into columns of a dataframe, but am struggling to find a simple command. Usually, I would save them to a list, but want to know if there is simple way of doing this. Each list within a tuple for `Name` would be considered a row in the dataframe Thanks.

```
    Name        column1   column2  column3
    Andrew         1          0       100
    Sam            1          0       100  
    Sam            2          0       100
    Sam            3          0       100
    Sam            4          0       100
    Susan          1          1       50
```

Comment: what's behind `...`? Are they all 3-tuples or are they different sizes? What to make of Susan's data? Is it just a single long list? You need to be more specific here

Comment: They are all tulples. Each tuple contains three lists of the same length.

Comment: so could you update your question to reflect that?

Comment: Just updated it.

Comment: **`df.explode()`**. This is a duplicate. Not of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62322092/converting-tuples-in-a-row-to-a-new-columns-in-pandas-dataframe) but of e.g. [Explode Cell into Multiple Rows in Pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65799353/explode-cell-into-multiple-rows-in-pandas/). Or all the other questions on exploding tuples.